# Making computation-threads cancellable in a smart way

Tags: java, multithreading, performance

I am wondering how to reach a compromise between fast-cancel-responsiveness and performance with my threads which body look similar to this loop:

```
for(int i=0; i<HUGE_NUMBER; ++i) {
    //some easy computation like adding numbers
    //which are result of previous iteration of this loop
}
```

If a computation in loop body is quite easy then adding simple check-reaction to each iteration:

```
if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
    throw new InterruptedException("Cancelled");            
}
```

may **slow down** execution of the code.

Even if I change the above condition to:

```
if (i % 100 && Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
    throw new InterruptedException("Cancelled");            
}
```

Then compilator cannot just precompute values of `i` and check condition only in some specific situations since `HUGE_NUMBER` is variable and can have different values.

So I'd like to ask if there's any **smart way** of adding such check to a presented code knowing that:

- `HUGE_NUMBER` is variable and can have different values
- loop body consists of some easy-to-compute, but relying on prevoius computations code.

What I want to say is that one iteration of a loop is quite fast, but `HUGE_NUMBER` of iterations can take a little more time and this is what I want to avoid.

Comment: What do you mean with "compilator cannot just precompute values of i and check condition only in some specific situations"?

Comment: To be honest, I don't really know all performance-tunings which may appear after handing your code to compilator. I just know that if loop is set to iterate over constant number then it may be simple expanded (inlined). Since `HUGE_NUMBER` is a variable - it cannot simply assume its value and perform optimalizations (possibly JIT can - but this is part of my question - if JIT can optimize this code then adding check to each loop iteration does not slow it down).

Comment: Why don't you wait until you are sure this is a performance bottleneck. I doubt that checking the thread interruption state is going to take long. And I don't think JIT's inlining depends on staticly defined loop cycles. Also, you may consider using ```Thread.interrupted()``` method instead. Since ```isInterrupted()``` does not resets state.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo I never said that JIT's inlining depends on statically defined loop cycles. It's also not kind of practical question - when I have a problem and write it here to get help in solving it. **It's clearly theoretical question**. Using `Thread.interruped()` leads me to the same situation when I have to check if it returns true or false - clearing thread state is not always wanted. I just want to know if I can avoid calling external methods in `if` in every loop iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, use `Thread.interrupted()` instead of `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` in that case.

You should think about if checking the interruption flag really slows down your calculation too much! One the one hand, if the loop body is VERY simple, even a huge number of iterations (the upper limit is Integer.MAX_VALUE) will run in a few seconds. Even when checking the interruption flag will result in an overhead of 20 or 30%, this will not add very much to the total runtime of your algorithm.

On the other hand, if the loop body is not that simple and so it will run longer, testing the interruption flag will not be a remarkable overhead I think.

Don't do tricks like `if (i % 10000 == 0)`, as this will slow down calculation much more than a 'short' `Thread.interrupted()`.

There is one small trick that you could use - but think twice because it makes your code more complex and less readable:

Whenever you have a loop like that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    // loop-body using i
}
```

you can split up the total range of `i` into several intervals of size `INTERVAL_SIZE`:

```
int start = 0;
while (start < max) {       
    final int next = Math.min(start + INTERVAL_SIZE, max);
    for(int i = start; i < next; i++) {
        // loop-body using i
    }
    start = next;
}
```

Now you can add your interruption check right before or after the inner loop!

---

I've done some tests on my system (JDK 7) using the following loop-body

```
if (i % 2 == 0) x++;
```

and `Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2` iterations. The results are as follows (after warm-up):

- Simple loop without any interruption checks: **1,949 ms**
- Simple loop with check per iteration: **2,219 ms** (+14%)
- Simple loop with check per 1 million-th iteration using modulo: **3,166 ms** (+62%)
- Simple loop with check per 1 million-th iteration using bit-mask: **2,653 ms** (+36%)
- Interval-loop as described above with check in outer loop: **1,972 ms** (+1.1%)

*So even if the loop-body is as simple as above, the overhead for a per-iteration check is only 14%! So it's recommended to not do any tricks but **simply check the interruption flag via `Thread.interrupted()` in every iteration!***

Comment: `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` and clearing thread interruped status is not necessarily what I want. Btw. smart way to divide computations in several loops :)

Comment: Thx. Clearing the interruption flag is EXACTLY what you want in this case, because you're throwing an InterruptionException! That's usually how it's done: Either interruption flag is set, or InterruptionException is thrown. Also see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html (read last line!)

Comment: Thanks for doing the timings.  I can delete my answer now!

Comment: @isnot2bad Thanks for giving your test results! It can be really pointless to rise complexity of the code just to save ~14% of execution time.

Answer (score 1):

Make your calculation an `Iterator`.

Although this does not sound terribly useful the benefit here is that you can then quite easily write filter iterators that can be surprisingly flexible. They can be added and removed simply - even through configuration if you wish. There are a number of benefits - try it.

You can then add a filtering `Iterator` that watches the time and checks for interrupt on a regular basis - or something even more flexible.

You can even add further filtering without compromising the original calculation by interspersing it with brittle status checks.

Comment: Thanks, it's **really** interesting approach - have you tried it in your code?

Comment: @MaciejDobrowolski - Yes I have - many times - and the discipline required to turn a loop into an `Iterator` teaches you more about the algorithm you are implementing than you would expect.